# Inheritance/classes in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am new to C#, and are trying to understand classes and "is a" relationships. I've been trying to get a piece of code to work, but I can't seem to get it right.

It looks like this: http://pastebin.com/cQDusptB

I have a base class, Mammal, which one should be able to create instances of, giving the name of the mammal as input.
I also have a class, Dog, which is a Mammal. One should be able to create an instance of this too, in the same manner as Mammal.

Can anyone see my flaw(s)? If yes, can you please explain what i misunderstood/forgot?

Comment: You can include a small example of the problem you're having right in your question. Pastebin not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here.  For one, constructors can not be marked as virtual or overridden.  Another problem is that you attempt to call the method `.Name` without parentheses.  The corrected version looks like this:

```
public class Mammal
{
    protected string _Name;

    public virtual string Name()
    {
            return (this._Name + " - of type " + this.GetType());
    }
    public Mammal(string Name)
    {
        this._Name = Name;
    }
}
public class Dog : Mammal
{
    public Dog(string Name) : base(Name)
    {
    }

    public override string Name()
    {
        return (base._Name + "Dog");
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Mammal AnimalA = new Mammal("SubjectA");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", AnimalA.Name());

    Mammal AnimalB = new Dog("SubjectB");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", AnimalB.Name());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! - I understand the changes! - I'm wondering though, is there any easy workaround, if i wanted to just call .Name without the () ?

Comment: Use [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

When posting questions like this it is helpful to also post the error message the compiler gave you.

> Can anyone see my flaw(s)?

You have a virtual constructor.

> can you please explain what i misunderstood/forgot?

Constructors are *not inherited* in C# and therefore it makes no sense to mark them as either *virtual* or *override*.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of Dog needs to be named "Dog". You can't/don't need to override "Mammal". Also, Mammal's constructor shouldn't be virtual.

```
public class Mammal 
{

    public Mammal(string name)
    {
        //....
    }
}

public class Dog : Mammal {

    public Dog(string name) : base(name) 
    {
    }
}
```

You pass arguments to the base class constructor using the "base" keyword (see code above).

Be sure to pick up a good book on C# to get the language basics right.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense :) - I have a book, but I didn't quite get its explanation of this part :(

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not inherited/overridden.

- Lose the 'virtual' keyword from the Mammal constructor in the Mammal class.
- Remove the Mammal ctor override attempt in the Dog class.
- Replace it with a Dog constructor that calls the Mammal one (like this):

public Dog(string name) : base(name)
{

}

Now when a dog is constructed it will call through to the mammal base class constructor passing the specified name.